# "Hinwillst" or "willst hin" in a subclause? And why is "Du" capitalized?

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause, separable-verb, capitalization

Verliere nie Deinen Fokus darauf, wo **Du** **hinwillst**.

hinwillst ...should be wollst hin, right?

Why is it hinwillst here?

And why is Du capitalized?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The capitalized *Du* is old orthography. Before the *Rechtschreibreform* in the 1990s is was common in letters to write forms of *du* (*du, dich, dir, dein* etc.) with a capital D to honor the recipient.

"Hinwollen" is a composed verb here. See https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hinwollen

In a subordinate clause like this, there's no reason to separate it. So

> Verliere nie Deinen Fokus darauf, wo Du hinwillst.

is correct.

In a question or main clause, it would be different though:

> Wo willst du hin?

> Er will da unbedingt hin.

Comment: is this true of all other verbs of this kind like austehen

Comment: Pretty much. You mean aufstehen? "Ich weiß nicht, wann Lara morgen aufsteht." "Lara, wann stehst du morgen auf?" "Ich stehe immer um 7 Uhr auf."

Comment: There are verbs that don't separate at all, you probaly know that. "Ich frage mich, wann mich  das Motorrad überholt", "Wann überholst du den Laster?", "Das Motorrad überholt jetzt."

Comment: ... and then there are homonyms which are differentiated by whether they separate or not. E.g. "übersetzen" can mean "translate" (not separating "Ich übersetze.") or "use a ferry" (separating "Ich setze über").

Answer (score 1):

Separable verbs are only separated in sentences with a *Satzklammer*. That are basically main clauses with the verb in the second position:

> Du **willst** dort **hin**.

Subclauses do not have a *Satzklammer*. The verb comes at the end by default and is never seperated:

> Dort, wo du **hinwillst**.

Possible and stylistically maybe better, however, would be to use the relative pronoun *wohin* and drop the corresponding verb prefix instead:

> Verliere nie den Fokus darauf, **wohin** du willst.

This is a general pattern with the prefixes *hin-*, *her-*, *hinein-* and *(he)raus-*:

> - Vergiss nie, wo du herkommst.
> - Vergiss nie, woher du kommst.

Capitalising *Du* in an address is old orthography. After a reform it's *du* nowadays.